# Concerns about Suspicious User Activity

Tags: bots, user-activity

I have a simple one-page web site and have seen some user activity that concerns me.  I use "ip-api.io/json" to limit access to my web site by spammers and other suspicious URLs.  Even with this, however, most of the URLs accessing my site are from outside the United States and in some cases, my site is opened multiple times (or refreshed multiple times) in a few seconds.

Today, for example, my website has been accessed 24 times by a single URL in Colombia.  I find it difficult to believe that my site has such interest for anyone in Colombia.  Is this some kind of bot activity or other suspicious user activity that I should be concerned about?  If yes, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a bot unless the IP doesn't belong to a cellular Internet provider and your website is that popular. You better have some details what part/port of the website has been accessed 24 times. For example, if it's a login page (which is not you case, I suppose, because you mentioned it's a simple one-page), or someone tries your server via port 22 - well, you guess.

Comment: You're right, Battle_Slug.  I don't have a login page.  Just some information and a contact us page.  I'm an environmental, health and safety consultant in Florida.  I'm in no position to offer services outside of the United States, yet better than 80% of the users accessing my site are from IP addresses outside of the United States.  I'm a bit of a novice in this area.  Is there a way that I can identify the server port that they are accessing?

Comment: I'm not familiar what are the tools you use, but basically all the interesting information is in your nginx or apache logs (whatever server you use).